# How to install missing shared library files: DMGMPI and FMPICH on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, fortran, mpi, gfortran

I am stuck with missing library files ("dmgmpi" & "fmpich") compilation errors which I need in order to compile a makefile. The error status after the compilation is:

```
bcdflt.o checkin.o  -L./ -ldmgmpi -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpich -lfmpich -ldl - 
lpthread -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lhdf -ldf -ljpeg -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldmgmpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfmpich
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:111: /home/subhokar/ZEUS-MP_2-master/CODE/zeusmp2/exe90/zeusmp.x] 
Error 1
```

I would like to mention that I have tried to locate them in my system but couldn't find them anywhere installed.
Can someone suggest me from where should I download and install them? I couldn't find anything over the Internet :(

Thanks in advance.

**Edit_1**:
Hi everyone! I am glad to have got your kind attention. Apologies for my mistakes while posting for the first time on this platform. As per asked, I would like to mention that I have mpicc library installed as a part of the gcc.exec (v10.2.0) on my system.  I am trying to install [ZEUS-MP-2](https://github.com/bwoshea/ZEUS-MP_2) on my Ubuntu (20.04lts) system using the provided makefile (*Makefile_Linux*).
The makefile that I am trying to compile using the installed GNU make (v4.2.1) is as follows:

```
#-------------------  macro definitions  -------------------------------
#
all: compile
ZMP_EXE   = /home/subhokar/ZEUS-MP_2-master/CODE/zeusmp2/exe90/
ZMP_MOD   = ./
ZMP_FC    = mpif90 -w
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment the next line to compile with agressive optimization
#ZMP_OPTS  = -FI -72 -c  -O2 -traceback -fpe0
ZMP_OPTS  = -FI -c -O 
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ZMP_CC    = gcc
ZMP_LDR   = mpif90
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# If libdmgmpi.a exists in src90, use the first definition of MGMPI_LIB.
# If MGMPI is not used at all, use the second definition.  If the library
# is located elsewhere, customize the first definition as needed.
MGMPI_LIB = -L./ -ldmgmpi
#MGMPI_LIB = -L./
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ZMP_LIB   = ${HDF} ${MGMPI_LIB} \
        -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpich -ldl -lpthread \
                -L/usr/local/hdf5/lib -lhdf5 -ljpeg -lz
ZMP_CPP   = /lib/cpp -DPROBLEM=blast -DPROBRES=empty \
            -DMPI_USED -DUSE_MGMPI \
            -DMPI_FLOAT=MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION -DMPI_2FLOAT=MPI_2DOUBLE_PRECISION
#
#--------------------  implicit rules  ---------------------------------
#
.SUFFIXES: .F .f .c .o

.f.o:
    ${ZMP_CPP} -P -traditional $*.F | tr -s "" "\012" > $*.f
    ${ZMP_FC} -I ${ZMP_MOD} ${ZMP_OPTS} $*.f

.F.o:
    ${ZMP_CPP} -P -traditional $*.F | tr -s "" "\012" > $*.f
    ${ZMP_FC} -I ${ZMP_MOD} ${ZMP_OPTS} $*.f

.c.o:
    ${ZMP_CC} -c $<

#
#-------------------  Fortran object files  ----------------------------
#
FOBJ = mod_files.o advx1.o advx2.o advx3.o alloc_arrays.o avisc.o avisc_d.o bndyflgs.o bval3d.o bvalabuns.o bvalemf.o bvalt.o cgsolve.o clocks.o configure.o ct.o ct_1D.o ct_2D.o dataio.o difco1.o difco2.o difco3.o diverg.o dprd.o empty.o eos_d.o eos.o fftwgrav.o findno.o forces.o forces_d.o ggen.o gpbv.o gravity.o gravmg.o grav2dcg.o grav3dcg.o grdv.o hdfall.o hsmoc.o hsmoc_1D.o hsmoc_2D.o grey_fld.o intchk.o jacob.o lorentz.o lorentz_1D.o lorentz_2D.o lorentz_d.o mapin.o mapout.o matprop.o mnmx.o momx1.o momx2.o momx3.o msave.o msendrec.o mstart.o mul_sym.o offdiag.o newdt.o newgrid.o newvg.o newx1.o newx2.o newx3.o nudt.o opac_d.o opacity.o options.o pdv.o pdv_d.o rad_imp_dt.o rad_solve.o restart.o sendrec.o setup.o srcstep.o strtoi.o sym_diag.o sym_prcn.o transprt.o transprt_1D.o transprt_2D.o tranx1.o tranx2.o tranx3.o updtmtrxbnd.o updtvecbnd.o zeusmp.o gcollapse.o textdmp.o  linpck.o sod.o blast.o sedov.o stream.o rshock.o mhdshktube.o rotor.o mhdvortex.o noh.o marshak.o
#
#-------------------  C object files  ----------------------------------
#
COBJ = bcdflt.o checkin.o
#
#---------------------  targets  ---------------------------------------
#
help:
    @echo Type "'make help'             to see this menu"
    @echo Type "'make compile           to create executable
    @echo Type "'make clean'            to remove '*.f' and '*.o' files"
    @echo Type "'make cleaner'          to remove '*.f' '*.o' "
    @echo "                             ${ZMP_EXE}zmp_inp ${ZMP_EXE}zeusmp.x"
    @echo Type "'make listing'          to create listing of code"
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
NPFOBJ = setup.f restart.f textdmp.f forces.f hdfall.f opacity.f matprop.f bval3d.f difco1.f difco2.f difco3.f
NPOOBJ = setup.o restart.o textdmp.o forces.o hdfall.o opacity.o matprop.o bval3d.o difco1.o difco2.o difco3.o

newprob:
    \rm -f ${NPFOBJ} ${NPOOBJ}
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
clean:
    echo "\rm -f *.o *.f *.mod"
    \rm -f *.o *.f *.mod
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
cleaner:
    echo "\rm -f *.o *.f *.mod  ${ZMP_EXE}zmp_inp ${ZMP_EXE}zeusmp.x"
    \rm -f *.o *.f  ${ZMP_EXE}zmp_inp ${ZMP_EXE}zeusmp.x
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
listing:
    echo "cat Makefile  *.h *.F *.c > listing"
    cat Makefile  *.h *.F *.c > listing
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
compile: ${ZMP_EXE}zeusmp.x

${ZMP_EXE}zeusmp.x: ${FOBJ} ${COBJ}
    ${ZMP_LDR} -o ${ZMP_EXE}zeusmp.x ${FOBJ} ${COBJ} ${ZMP_LIB}

#
#----------------------  dependencies  ---------------------------------
#
mod_files.o: mod_files.F 

advx1.o: advx1.F mod_files.o  

advx2.o: advx2.F mod_files.o  

advx3.o: advx3.F mod_files.o  

alloc_arrays.o: alloc_arrays.F mod_files.o

avisc.o: avisc.F mod_files.o  

avisc_d.o: avisc_d.F mod_files.o  

bndyflgs.o: bndyflgs.F mod_files.o  

bval3d.o: bval3d.F mod_files.o  

bvalabuns.o: bvalabuns.F mod_files.o  

bvalemf.o: bvalemf.F mod_files.o  

bvalt.o: bvalt.F mod_files.o  

cgsolve.o: cgsolve.F mod_files.o

clocks.o: clocks.F mod_files.o  

configure.o: configure.F mod_files.o  

ct.o: ct.F mod_files.o  

ct_1D.o: ct_1D.F mod_files.o  

ct_2D.o: ct_2D.F mod_files.o  

dataio.o: dataio.F mod_files.o  

difco1.o: difco1.F mod_files.o

difco2.o: difco2.F mod_files.o

difco3.o: difco3.F mod_files.o

diverg.o: diverg.F mod_files.o  

dprd.o: dprd.F mod_files.o

empty.o: empty.F  

eos_d.o: eos_d.F mod_files.o

eos.o: eos.F mod_files.o

findno.o: findno.F  

forces.o: forces.F mod_files.o  

forces_d.o: forces_d.F mod_files.o  

fourn.o: fourn.F  

ggen.o: ggen.F mod_files.o  

gravity.o: gravity.F mod_files.o  

gravmg.o: gravmg.F mod_files.o  

grav2dcg.o: grav2dcg.F mod_files.o  

grav3dcg.o: grav3dcg.F mod_files.o  

grdv.o: grdv.F mod_files.o

gpbv.o: gpbv.F mod_files.o

grdv.o: grdv.F mod_files.o  

hdfall.o: hdfall.F mod_files.o  

hsmoc.o: hsmoc.F mod_files.o  

hsmoc_1D.o: hsmoc_1D.F mod_files.o  

hsmoc_2D.o: hsmoc_2D.F mod_files.o  

grey_fld.o: grey_fld.F mod_files.o

intchk.o: intchk.F mod_files.o  

jacob.o: jacob.F mod_files.o

lorentz.o: lorentz.F mod_files.o  

lorentz_1D.o: lorentz_1D.F mod_files.o  

lorentz_2D.o: lorentz_2D.F mod_files.o  

lorentz_d.o: lorentz_d.F mod_files.o  

mapin.o: mapin.F mod_files.o  

mapout.o: mapout.F mod_files.o  

matprop.o: matprop.F mod_files.o

msendrec.o: msendrec.F mod_files.o

mnmx.o: mnmx.F mod_files.o  

momx1.o: momx1.F mod_files.o  

momx2.o: momx2.F mod_files.o  

momx3.o: momx3.F mod_files.o  

msave.o: msave.F mod_files.o  

mstart.o: mstart.F mod_files.o  

mul_sym.o: mul_sym.F mod_files.o

newdt.o: newdt.F mod_files.o  

newgrid.o: newgrid.F  mod_files.o

newvg.o: newvg.F mod_files.o

newx1.o: newx1.F mod_files.o

newx2.o: newx2.F mod_files.o

newx3.o: newx3.F mod_files.o

nudt.o: nudt.F mod_files.o  

offdiag.o: offdiag.F mod_files.o

opac_d.o: opac_d.F mod_files.o

opacity.o: opacity.F mod_files.o

options.o: options.F mod_files.o 

pdv.o: pdv.F mod_files.o  

pdv_d.o: pdv_d.F mod_files.o  

rad_imp_dt.o: rad_imp_dt.F mod_files.o

rad_solve.o: rad_solve.F mod_files.o

restart.o: restart.F mod_files.o  

sendrec.o: sendrec.F mod_files.o

setup.o: setup.F mod_files.o  

srcstep.o: srcstep.F mod_files.o  

strtoi.o: strtoi.F  

sym_diag.o: sym_diag.F mod_files.o

sym_prcn.o: sym_prcn.F mod_files.o

tmul_sym.o: tmul_sym.F mod_files.o

transprt.o: transprt.F mod_files.o  

transprt_1D.o: transprt_1D.F mod_files.o  

transprt_2D.o: transprt_2D.F mod_files.o  

tranx1.o: tranx1.F mod_files.o  

tranx2.o: tranx2.F mod_files.o  

tranx3.o: tranx3.F mod_files.o  

updtmtrxbnd.o: updtmtrxbnd.F mod_files.o  

updtvecbnd.o: updtvecbnd.F mod_files.o  

zeusmp.o: zeusmp.F mod_files.o  

textdmp.o: textdmp.F mod_files.o  

linpck.o: linpck.F mod_files.o  

bcdflt.o: bcdflt.c  

checkin.o: checkin.c  

rotor.o: rotor.F mod_files.o  

mhdvortex.o: mhdvortex.F mod_files.o  

mhdshktube.o: mhdshktube.F mod_files.o  

blast.o: blast.F mod_files.o  

gcollapse.o: gcollapse.F mod_files.o  

sedov.o: sedov.F mod_files.o  

sod.o: sod.F mod_files.o  

stream.o: stream.F mod_files.o

marshak.o: marshak.F mod_files.o

rshock.o: rshock.F mod_files.o

noh.o: noh.F mod_files.o

fftw_ps.o: fftw_ps.c

fftwplan.o: fftwplan.c
```

The command at the terminal I am issuing for the compilation is:

```
make
```

The compilation output that I am getting is:

```
    mpif90 -o /home/subhokar/ZEUS-MP_2 master/CODE/zeusmp2/exe90/zeusmp.x mod_files.o advx1.o advx2.o advx3.o alloc_arrays.o avisc.o avisc_d.o bndyflgs.o bval3d.o bvalabuns.o bvalemf.o bvalt.o cgsolve.o clocks.o configure.o ct.o ct_1D.o ct_2D.o dataio.o difco1.o difco2.o difco3.o diverg.o dprd.o empty.o eos_d.o eos.o fftwgrav.o findno.o forces.o forces_d.o ggen.o gpbv.o gravity.o gravmg.o grav2dcg.o grav3dcg.o grdv.o hdfall.o hsmoc.o hsmoc_1D.o hsmoc_2D.o grey_fld.o intchk.o jacob.o lorentz.o lorentz_1D.o lorentz_2D.o lorentz_d.o mapin.o mapout.o matprop.o mnmx.o momx1.o momx2.o momx3.o msave.o msendrec.o mstart.o mul_sym.o offdiag.o newdt.o newgrid.o newvg.o newx1.o newx2.o newx3.o nudt.o opac_d.o opacity.o options.o pdv.o pdv_d.o rad_imp_dt.o rad_solve.o restart.o sendrec.o setup.o srcstep.o strtoi.o sym_diag.o sym_prcn.o transprt.o transprt_1D.o transprt_2D.o tranx1.o tranx2.o tranx3.o updtmtrxbnd.o updtvecbnd.o zeusmp.o gcollapse.o textdmp.o  linpck.o sod.o blast.o sedov.o stream.o rshock.o mhdshktube.o rotor.o mhdvortex.o noh.o marshak.o bcdflt.o checkin.o  -L./ -ldmgmpi -L/usr/lib -lmpich -lfmpich -ldl -lpthread -L/usr/lib -lmfhdf -ldf -ljpeg -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldmgmpi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfmpich
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please let me know if any other information is needed to be mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Do you have an MPI library installed? Which one? Which exact command produced this error output? Please show us the complete output. See also [mcve].

Comment: which program are you trying to install?

Comment: `libfmpich.so` should be provided by `mpich`, which version of MPICH is installed on your system?

Comment: it seems `libfmpich.so` has been renamed into `libmpichfort.so`. you are likely building a code that has not been modernized.

Comment: Normally, one should not care if linking using `mpif90` or similar wrappers. This is why I insist on showing us the complete commands being executed.

Comment: Re: -ldmgmpi comments at https://github.com/belfhi/Zeus-MP2/blob/master/src90/Makefile.SN1D might be useful. Re:  -lfmpich as a first guess I would just cut it (and -lmpich) out - you are linking with mpif90 and this should link these automatically.